# Ruby: How to check if a string is a valid time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, time

I'm pulling data from a feed that I have no control over and I need to verify if a string I'm given is a valid time.

Most of the time I'm correctly sent something like "2:35" or "15:41" but other times it's things like "AM" or "PM" (and no numbers)...so I ultimately just need to ignore those.

So, how can I verify if the data is a valid time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Time.parse()](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000305) is **not a good solution**, as shown in the example of the comments.

I'll leave the answer here for 'historical reasons', to keep the comments, and as a warning for future readers!

---

You can use [Time.parse()](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000305) and check for the `ArgumentError` exception for invalid times.

Extra advantage is that you also have the time in a usable format to work with if it is valid!

Comment: Don't use parse to validate! Time.parse('2:34-^5') # => 2012-08-14 02:34:00 -0400

Comment: Using parse to validate may result in some missed invalid times, e.g.: `Time.parse('27:45 PM')` => 2012-12-04 15:45:00 -0500

Comment: Yes Time.parse is not a proper way to validate `DateTime.parse('monoxide')`
 => #<DateTime: 2019-11-25T00:00:00+00:00>

Answer (score 10):

You haven't exactly specified what you assume to be a valid time (e.g. whether you should accept optional seconds), so here's one guess:

```
date =~ /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])\:[0-5][0-9]$/
```

Comment: although Time.parse() with a rescue can work, I'd prefer the regex solution. Exceptions in ruby aren't considered really fast, so unless you need the time object, this is the advice I'd go with.

Comment: Using regex brings problems on its own: lots of different time formats making in very complicated to check whether the given time is valid. When you want to support all/most possible time formats you're basically reimplementing the `Time.parse()` method...

Comment: All depends how strict you like to be when accepting values. I presumed maximum strictness (only optional thing being a leading zero in hours). The question doesn't specify. In addition to that, `Time.parse` seems to be really really liberal when it comes to arguments. Try, for example: `Time.parse '10'` and `Time.parse 'asd'`. Neither throws an exception (at least in 1.9.1). I really wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: You can also try `Chronic.parse` which is pretty forgiving. The regex is the most concrete way to get a specific format or set of formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of the time you could use [`Time.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/stdlibs/time/Time.html#method-c-strptime):

> Works similar to parse except that instead of using a heuristic to
> detect the format of the input string, you provide a second argument
> that describes the format of the string.

It raises `ArgumentError` if the date or format is invalid.

An example:

```
require 'time'
Time.strptime("1970-01-01 08:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```