# Time validation in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, rubygems

I try to validate an input time in `hh:mm` format, so if the user enters time like `he:mm:ss` it should throw an error.

My function:

```
def update_booking_time 
  # Here need to validate time string
end
```

I tried with time parse, but I'm not sure how it's working

So how to achieve it?

Comment: There are many ways I could respond to your question.... I could ask "why would you care if the user entered a number of seconds?", or I could ask "why are you requiring the user to enter a time as a raw string, instead of using some built-in browser input [like this](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/time_field)?"

Comment: Like, do you have two separate input fields for "day" and "time"? (Why?) And I presume such a solution doesn't take into consideration the timezone, but maybe that's not a problem for you.

Comment: Anyway... If you really are insistent that you'd like the user input to be a raw string like `"16:34"`, then I can write a little method to validate it as you describe; I'm just a little unconvinced that it's actually a great solution to the problem.

Comment: See also, previous answers to similar questions e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2810875/1954610

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use [strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) method to create a date object from any format.

```
require 'time'
time = DateTime.strptime('03-02-2001 04:05:06 PM', '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p')#=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T16:05:06+00:00 ...>
```

Then you can use [strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) to format according to the directives in the given format string

```
time.strftime("at %I:%M %p")                 #=> "at 04:05 PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Time.strptime fo this. It takes two arguments, string to parse and expected time format, raising an exception when the string is not correct:

```
Time.strptime('10:11:15', '%T') #=> 2022-02-21 10:11:15 +0000
Time.strptime('25:00:15', '%T') #=> ArgumentError, invalid date or strptime format
```

(`%T` is a shortcut for `%H:%M:%S` - more formatting options explained [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime))