# pattern match in ruby for time

Tags: regex, ruby

I build a pattern match for the following time formats
4:05am or 11:03pm

it works on [rubular](https://rubular.com/r/T0Ajyra55d1NkZ) but irb does not find a match. How can I fix it?

```
irb(main):568:0> "4:00am" =~ /[\d+:\d{2}(a|p)m]/
```

=> 0

Comment: [] indicates a character class.

Comment: @Schwern Good catch. How did they get in there?

Comment: You can use [Time.parse](https://ruby-doc.com/stdlib/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) instead.

Comment: i reviewed the recommendation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810875/ruby-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-time and decided that regex is probably best. but need to find a way to make it work.

Comment: removing the box bracket does not work either
irb(main):569:0> "4:00am" =~ /\d+:\d{2}(a|p)m/
=> 0

Comment: _"irb does not find a match"_ – FYI: [`=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D~) returns the _position_ of the match so `=> 0` means that it found a match at index 0, i.e. right at the beginning of your string. A non-match would return `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, you have put your regex in brackets which indicate a character class. Easy enough to fix.

```
irb(main):001:0> "4:00am" =~ /\d+:\d{2}(a|p)m/
=> 0
```

But this would also work for:

```
irb(main):002:0> "4:70am" =~ /\d+:\d{2}(a|p)m/
=> 0
```

Instead you may want to specify that the `:` can be followed by the digits 0-5 and then by any digit.

```
irb(main):005:0> "4:50am" =~ /\d+:[0-5]\d(a|p)m/
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> "4:70am" =~ /\d+:[0-5]\d(a|p)m/
=> nil
```

But this can still detect a crazy time like `"14:40am"`. Given that it picks up on AM/PM, we can assume a 12 hour clock and modify your regular expression still further:

```
irb(main):009:0> "14:40am" =~ /^(\d|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d(a|p)m$/
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> "12:40am" =~ /^(\d|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d(a|p)m$/
=> 0
```

Comment: I suggest `(a|p)` be replaced with `(?:a|p)` or (better) `[ap]`. By using a capture group rather than a non-capture group (or a character class) the reader may think you intend to later use the contents of the capture group. In general, I suggest that capture groups only be used when their contents are needed.

Comment: Agreed. Though I was trying to make incremental changes to the original.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete regex for matching time values, we can use the one from the [Regexp::Common::time](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::time) Perl module. You can get this by installing the module and printing `$RE{time}{hms}`.

```
(?:(?<!\d)(?:(?:(?=\d)(?:[01]\d|2[0123]|(?<!\d)\d)))[:.\x20](?:(?:[0-5]\d))(?:[:.\x20](?:\d\d))?(?:\s?(?:(?:(?=[AaPp])(?:[ap](?:m|\.m\.)?|[AP](?:M|\.M\.)?))))?)
```

> The hour must be in the range 0 to 24. The minute and second values must be in the range 0 to 59, and must be two digits (i.e., they must have leading zeroes if less than 10).
>
> The hour, minute, and second components may be separated by colons (:), periods, or spaces.
>
> The "seconds" value may be omitted.
>
> The time may be followed by an "am/pm" indicator; that is, one of the following values:
>
> a   am   a.m.  p   pm   p.m.   A   AM   A.M.  P   PM   P.M.
>
> There may be a space between the time and the am/pm indicator.

```
3.1.2 :018 > re = %r{(?:(?<!\d)(?:(?:(?=\d)(?:[01]\d|2[0123]|(?<!\d)\d)))[:.\x20](?:(?:[0-5]\d))(?:[
:.\x20](?:\d\d))?(?:\s?(?:(?:(?=[AaPp])(?:[ap](?:m|\.m\.)?|[AP](?:M|\.M\.)?))))?)}
 => /(?:(?<!\d)(?:(?:(?=\d)(?:[01]\d|2[0123]|(?<!\d)\d)))[:.\x20](?:(?:[0-5]\d))(?:[:.\x20](?:... 
3.1.2 :019 > re.match('12:59 a.m.')
 => #<MatchData "12:59 a.m."> 
3.1.2 :020 > re.match('12:59 a.m. and stuff')
 => #<MatchData "12:59 a.m."> 
3.1.2 :021 > re.match('12:59 z.m.')
 => #<MatchData "12:59"> 
3.1.2 :022 > re.match('13:59 a.m.')
 => #<MatchData "13:59 a.m."> 
3.1.2 :023 > re.match('99:59 a.m.')
 => nil 
3.1.2 :024 > re.match('11:60 a.m.')
 => nil 
3.1.2 :026 > re.match('4:12')
 => #<MatchData "4:12"> 
3.1.2 :027 > re.match('4:1')
 => nil
```

Comment: "The minute and second values must be in the range 0 to 59" – This is wrong. It is possible to have minutes with 61 seconds.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ahh, [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).